# Hibernate HQL Alias Issue

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

```
MainTable.java extends Common.java

private Long id ;
private Long version ; 
private String name ;
private SubTable sub ;


SubTable.java extends Common.java

private String subname ;
prviate String dualname ; 


Common.java

private Long id ;
prviate Date createDate ;


HQL
v
String sql = "update MainTable set name = ?  where sub.id = ? and version = ?" ; 
Query query = session..createQuery(sql);
// set paramerts
query.executeUpdate();
```

Hibernate Generated SQL

update MainTable set name =? where templateve0_.SUB_ID=? and version =?

Error

ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-00904: "TEMPLATEVE0_"."SUB_ID": invalid identifier

FYI - SUB_ID is a valid column name.

I am not sure why is hibernate adding templateve0_ alias only for the sub-object. Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to update via SQL while you are using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original -
String sql = "update MainTable set name = ?  where sub.id = ? and version = ?" ;

Updated
String sql = "update MainTable set name = ?  where SUB_ID = ? and version = ?" ;

I replaced sub.id with the actual column name and it seems to be working! Very Strange!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alias to the root entity:

```
update MainTable m set m.name = :name where m.sub.id = :id and m.version = :version
```

(NOTE: I prefer named vars to ordinal ones)